# Jquery not running on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is a authors name loader 
when click on a letter form A -- Z 
 
it Will send an ajax request of this page 
authors/letters/ [Letter Value]

the problem is the Jquery in the loaded page doesn't work 
so is there any way that i can make jquery work after calling page in ajax

```
    var startlink='authors/letters/ALL';
    $.post(startlink,{},function(data){$('div#ajax-loader').html(data);});

    $('#letters a').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $.post(link,{},function(data){
       $('div#ajax-loader').empty();
      $('div#ajax-loader').load(data);

    });

    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to place your function calls in the parent page (the one you are calling your AJAX from) this will allow you to exec the functions contained in the AJAX request. failing that there is another method but I would not advise using it but it is a possible to use `eval`

Assuming the links you want to intercept are the ones in your code, you could always change it to:

```
$('#letters a').live("click", function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $.post(link,{},function(data){
        $('div#ajax-loader').empty();
        $('div#ajax-loader').load(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: `live` is now deprecated but still works, this has been replaced with `on` :)